# I already add mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar file in project folder, still get this error

Tags: java, jdbc

I already add mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar file in project folder [eclipse], still get this error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.MYSQL.jdbc.Driver"

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dvkM.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The driver name is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` (or better: `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` as `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` has been deprecated and loading it will log a warning), note the lowercase `mysql`, instead of `MYSQL` in your error. As an aside, loading the driver explicitly has not been needed - except in some corner cases - since 2006 (Java 6 / JDBC 4.0).